# using Java temporary file for XLSX Apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xlsx, temporary-files

.hi, i am trying to create a temporary .xlsx file and write to it using apache poi. i am getting EmptyFileException for creating workbook. this  is the code:

```
public class Writer{
File file;
public File Write(List<FormData> l, Class elementClass)
{

    try {//create temp fiele here
        file = File.createTempFile(elementClass.getSimpleName(),".xlsx");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Writer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    XSSFWorkbook workbook;
    XSSFSheet sheet;
    if (file.exists()) {
        FileInputStream inputStream;
        try {
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            throw new AspirinException(AspirinException.Type.INTERNAL_ERROR);
        }
        try {// this line gets error//
            workbook = (XSSFWorkbook) WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);
        } catch (IOException | InvalidFormatException | EncryptedDocumentException ex) {
            throw new AspirinException(AspirinException.Type.INTERNAL_ERROR);
        }

        //...
```

it works fine if i use a real file. but for temp file it doesn't work. please help me with this. thanks

Comment: Which error and where / on which line ?

Comment: What do you think will your `file` be else than an empty file? `WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream)` tries creating a `Workbook`object containing data read from the `inputStream`. This fails if there is no data to read.

Comment: WorkbookFactory.create () is used for existing/filled Excel files. Create a XSSFWorkbook from scratch and then write () it to your tempfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new file you will not need a file first, you can just start with a new Workbook:

```
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
```

and then use the API to populate it. At the end you can write it to a new file via

```
try (OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
    wb.write(stream);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`WorkbookFactory.create` API needs an `InputStream` which supports mark or reset.
You should try using `BufferedInputStream`.
Note that     `WorkbookFactory.create(java.io.File` file is recommended as it has smaller memory footprint.

Comment: I don't think this will work, the problem is that the code is reading from an empty file and it still will fail with File-based reading as well.