# Saving a QUERY request in the repository to an EXCEL file

Tags: java, excel, postgresql, spring-boot

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(value = "SELECT pp.id, pp.created_dt, au.username, ss.name, pp.amount,\n" +
            "REPLACE(pp.status, 'SUCCESS', 'Success') AS status, pp.account,\n" +
            "pp.external_id, COALESCE(pp.external_status, null, 'Indefined') AS external_status\n" +
            "FROM payments AS pp\n" +
            "INNER JOIN auth_user AS au ON au.id = pp.creator_id\n" +
            "INNER JOIN services AS ss ON ss.id = pp.service_id\n" +
            "WHERE pp.created_dt::date = (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1' day)::date\n" +
            "AND ss.name = 'SomeName' AND pp.status = 'SUCCESS'", nativeQuery = true)
    List<User> findAll();
}
```

How can I save the result of this selection to an excel file?

Do not take it out anywhere (I mean, without any respons). It's just that later I will send this file by mail as a report.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into the apache poi libraries: https://www.codejava.net/coding/how-to-write-excel-files-in-java-using-apache-poi

You can use these libraries using the following maven dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
```

You can [use temporal files to store the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854588/using-java-temporary-file-for-xlsx-apache-poi) and send it as a report, just remember to delete the file afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to use apache poi library. But I can't figure out in any way how should I link my SELECT to this library?